# JQuery Sortable not working - Object Expected Error

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie to JQuery. I have added the JQuery JS Source with UI-Core,Widget,Mouse and UI-Sortable. I have taken the following source from internet.

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Sortable - Portlets</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="../../jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">
<style>
.column { width: 170px; float: left; padding-bottom: 100px; }
.portlet { margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
.portlet-header { margin: 0.3em; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 0.2em; }
.portlet-header .ui-icon { float: right; }
.portlet-content { padding: 0.4em; }
.ui-sortable-placeholder { border: 1px dotted black; visibility: visible !important; height: 50px !important; }
.ui-sortable-placeholder * { visibility: hidden; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".column" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".column"
    });

    $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
        .find( ".portlet-header" )
            .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
            .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
            .end()
        .find( ".portlet-content" );

    $( ".portlet-header .ui-icon" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
        $( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    });

    $( ".column" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

It fails in the lines $( ".column" ).sortable({....}) and $( ".column" ).disableSelection() as "Object Expected Error". The two other lines in between passes with no issues while I was debugging it.

Can anyone help me out in this issue?

Comment: try it by adding reference to jquery-ui.min.js and jquery-ui.css

Comment: Jayantha,

Thanks for the reply. I have tried using jquery-ui.min.js but still it fails on the same lines. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have an element with `class="column"`, so the plugin throws an error because it doesn't find where to apply.

Hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks Edgar. 

<div class="demo"><div class="column"><div class="portlet"><div class="portlet-header">Alerts</div><div class="portlet-content">Text</div></div></div></div> 

I have <div> like above which has a class="column" but still it fails to find out that. Not sure why that happens.